# Show Sitecore Maintenance page on Site CD server

Tags: deployment

How can i show Sitecore maintenance page on Sitecore website while deployment.

We have load balancer environment with 6 CD servers but our client is not agree to remove CD server one by one from load balancer and add them again on load balancer after deployment, because this way it will increase deployment time from two hour to 4 hours.

I know there is a way to use `app_offline.htm` and put it on root of website directory but by using this our website warm up script is also not running as expected as script is also getting `app_offline.htm` page.

And also while deployment our Sitecore website is not responding otherwise we could use Sitecore pipeline to achieve this.

Please suggest what else we can do here to achieve this.

Comment: We have achieved this by using applicationInitialization in webconfig

Answer (score 1):

Create a new IIS Site with a single `index.html` static page that contains your maintenance content. You can put this on one of the CD servers (or multiple).

In the deployment script update the Load Balancer to route traffic through to the new maintenance page IIS Site, do the deployment, run the warm up scripts locally to each CD server and then once it is all ok, update the load balancer to route traffic back through to the Sitecore sites.